# Is the archive directory in Jenkins saved even if I set Max # of builds to keep to a number?

Tags: jenkins, build, directory, archive

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the archive directory.
From what I've seen, the archive is per build. Meaning if I set the 'Max # of builds to keep' to 3 for example, The archive will also be deleted.

Is that correct?

If so, how can I tell Jenkins to only save my artifact (zip file) created and delete the build directory?

Is there a one archive directory for all builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two directories for a Jenkins job,  by default (there can be just one, `builds`, in case of a *Workflow* job, or more, e.g. an additional `promotions` directory):

- `JENKINS_HOME/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/` containing sub-dirs according to `$BUILD_ID`
- `JENKINS_HOME/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/workspace/`

So, there's *one workspace per job* and *one build directory per build*.

---

[image]
Don't let the page [Administering Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) with [this change](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/diffpages.action?originalId=82019564&pageId=82019566) driven by [JENKINS-8446](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8446) confuse you. The workspace default, as also mentioned in the inline help (of the current v1.635 at the time of this writing), is still:

*Manage Jenkins → Configure System → Advanced... →   Workspace Root Directory*: `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace`

It's NOT `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}`.

---

If a discard of old builds takes place the workspace isn't discarded, but, since it exists per job, it is overwritten with every new build. Hence, if you'd like to keep old artifacts you can:

- create an "archive" job that uses the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and connect it as downstream to your build job.
- move them to some other location yourself (including creation of uniquely-named sub-dirs to store the artifact(s) in) using a **Post-build Action** → **Groovy Postbuild** or → **Execute a set of scripts**.

There's also the [Discard Old Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) which enhances Jenkins' built-in discard functionality via a **Post-build Action**.